# Dynamic bang finders in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, dynamic-finders, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 4 is getting rid of dynamic finders, so

```
User.find_by_hash(hash)
```

becomes

```
User.where(hash: hash) # .first
```

Okay, not a big deal. But what is the best way to deal do with dynamic bang finders like `User.find_by_hash!(hash)` since there is no `where!()` method? [Rails 4 Release Notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html) conveniently avoid this.

**Update**: It plainly says: "All dynamic methods EXCEPT for find_by_... and find_by_...! are deprecated."

Either the pages has changed since or I was blind when reading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It plainly says: "All dynamic methods EXCEPT for find_by_... and find_by_...! are deprecated."

Answer (score 2):

I think the new syntax is

```
User.find_by!(hash: hash)
```

At least that's how ryanb does it:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/400-what-s-new-in-rails-4

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the all version. I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you need a method that finds all but raises exception if the relation is empty, you can create such new method for your models yourself (or mixin to ActiveRecord::QueryMethods). Something like:

```
def where!(*args)
  rel = where(*args) 
  raise RecordNotFound if rel.empty?
  rel
end
```

Comment: Oh, right "All dynamic methods EXCEPT for find_by_... and find_by_...! are deprecated."

Either the pages has changed since or I was blind when reading it.